# Tag search bar not working in mobile version of Stack Overflow

Tags: bug, mobile-web, tag-search

I want to filter questions based on some tag that I enter in the search bar in the  Tag section of the mobile version of Stack Overflow. But when I write my tag name inside the search bar & hit enter, it does nothing. I tried entering the tag names inside square brackets as well but still nothing happens. At first I thought the problem would be with my browser so I switched to Google Chrome mobile version and guess what? It doesn't work there either. Why doesn't it work? is this some kind of known bug?

Browsers tested on:   Uc & Chrome

My Phone:   Lenovo p2

Os: Android   7

Comment: To be clear, do you mean the mobile browser or SE app or SO app? What phone/OS?

Comment: @Catija i edited my question take a look. Its mobile browser.

Comment: I'm confused. You don't say which browser you're using initially and then you say it does work in Chrome but you say "too".

Comment: I edited it with Browser used & my phone & os. Btw i just checked it from the brother's phone as well and it doesn't work there too. He has motog g3

Comment: No repro for me. but what you mean "hit enter" You mean tapping the search icon in the phone's keyboard?

Comment: @Shadow Wizard Yes tapping search icon in phone's keyboard.

Comment: I can repro here: Chrome on Android 8. However, searching for a `[tag]` in the question search works fine.

Comment: Actually, I take that last bit back. Searching for a `[tag]` just returns all questions. Seems like something is borked.

Comment: @ale I also tried it on my brother's phone who has Android 6. And it doesn't work there either. His phone is moto g3

Comment: Lol it doesn't work in Meta Stack Exchange as well. 

Comment: i just checked it in iphone 6s as well using default safari browser and guess what it doesn't work there either. 

Comment: where can i report it ?

Comment: You just did. Now we just have to wait, it might take few days/weeks/months before SE team will notice the bug report.

Comment: @ShadowWizard days/weeks/months/eternities... and more

Comment: @alexolut I said notice, not fix. ;)

Comment: @ShadowWizard I mean same ... notice :) Because "notice" in this case means adding [tag:status-planned] tag to the post at least.

Comment: @alexolut lol no, only 0.000001% of the bugs/requests they notice ever get such tag.

Comment: I can confirm. It's totally broken.

Comment: This is still not working 

Comment: I can't reproduce this in the latest Chrome on Android 7.1.2; if you're still seeing this, can you provide more details on which site & tags you're searching for? Maybe a screenshot...?

Comment: Useless edit just to bump the question isn't a nice thing to do. Anyway, since mobile web is about to be nuked soon when responsive design is completed, the bug is not relevant and likely they won't bother to fix any bugs related to mobile web.